# Finding number of Pythagorean triples within a given range

Tags: unix, c++, c

I am trying to write a program which prints Pythagorean triples (a^2 + b^2 = c^2) for a given range N where a<=b<=c<=N.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, N, T,c2;

  scanf("%d", &T);

  while(T--)
  {
    int counter = 0;
    scanf("%d", &N);
   {
     for (c = 0; c <=N; c++)
     {
       for (b = 0; b < c; b++)
       {
          for (a = 0; a < b; a++)
          {
             c2 = c*c;
            if (a*a + b*b == c2 )
            //if(sqrt (pow(a,2) + pow(b,2)) == c) 
            {
                ++counter;
                 printf("\n %d , %d, %d \n",a,b,c);   }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   printf("%d\n", counter);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

This works well for N<1000. For higher N, say 10000 this takes a lot of time.
Is there any better way to optimize this prog or any better algorithm instead of brute force, so that it takes less time to compute for higher N ?

Comment: a) This is a question for Stackoverflow. b) Project Euler?

Comment: ...or better not to SO, because it could be closed there too.

Comment: @deviantfan.. why would it be closed on S/O??  Just curious... this seems like a legit programming question unless I'm being really stupid and missing something

Comment: Because of: possible duplicate of [How to find pythagorean triplets in an array faster than O(N^2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032153/how-to-find-pythagorean-triplets-in-an-array-faster-than-on2)

Comment: Once 2 of `a`, `b`, `c` are fixed, the last can be computed directly without loop. (so in your case `a*a = c*c - b*b`)

Comment: Length Cannot be zero,so initialize a,b,c with '1'

Comment: you can skip the 3rd loop by doing `c*c - b*b` to find `a`. Of course, then you have to make sure that `a` is an integer and not something rounded from a value with decimal point

Comment: Length Cannot be zero,so initialize a,b,c with '1',This will save (N*N)+1 Iterations

Comment: I think you would be better off to first generate a list of squares that are less than some threshhold, then find those entries that are the sum of two other entries...

Answer (score 1):

By number theory, Pythagorean triples are parametrized by (2pq, p^2-q^2, p^2+q^2). You can enumerate over these and just abort whenever c > N. This is of course optimal since you do as many computations as there are triples...

Answer (score 0):

First, you can compute `c2` as soon as a new value of `c` is available:

```
 for (c = 0; c <=N; c++)
  {
   /* compute c2 here */
```

This saves the time to compute it over and over for each `b` and `a`.

The same goes for `b`: it is possible to compute the square of `b` as soon as `b` is available, instead of for each value of `a`. Your compiler may automatically apply these optimizations, but not necessarily.

Lastly, there is only one value of `a` that can make the equation true, and this value is `sqrt(c2 - b2)`. For large values of `b`, it is much faster to compute this expression and to check whether it makes the equation true than to test all values between `0` and `b`. If you use double-precision computation for `sqrt(c2 - b2)`, then floating-point approximations will not be an issue until `N` is about 2<sup>26</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce one variable by the following calculations. If we assume that

```
a = m^2 - n^2,  b = 2mn,  c = m^2 + n^2
```

Lets check if it satisfies `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`:

```
a^2+b^2 = (m^2 - n^2)^2 + (2mn)^2 = (m^2 + n^2)^2 = c^2.
```

Now, we can iterate through all possible `m` and `n` and generate corresponding `a`, `b`, `c`.

It's the fastest method I ever used. However, I don't know if there exist any `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` mathematical solutions.