# Given the co-ordinates of n points in 2-D plane, find the number of triplets that form right triangle

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I can obviously do this by brute force, by selecting all the triplets one by one and checking if they form a right triangle.
But what could be a more optimal way? I couldn't think of any.

edit: Since some of you pointed out another question seemingly similar to this one, I went through the answers and I still couldn't figure out how do I solve this one using those answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032153/how-to-find-pythagorean-triplets-in-an-array-faster-than-on2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find pythagorean triplets in an array faster than O(N^2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032153/how-to-find-pythagorean-triplets-in-an-array-faster-than-on2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in `O(n^2Log(n))`.

**Algo** :

Create a **2D array** `Slope`, where `Slope[i,j]` is slope vector between `coordinate[i]` and `coordinate[j]`.

Now, for `coordinate[i]` to be the **joint**(see note 2) of the **right angled triangle**, there should be two slopes in `Slope[i,....]` which are orthogonal to each other, i.e. their **dot products** are 0.

If `Slope[i,j] = (a,b)` `(in vector form)`, then you have to look for `(b,-a)` or `(-b,a)` in `Slope[i,....]`.

To make search optimized, keep the array `Slope[i,...]` sorted on `a` or `b`.
Sorting will take `O(nlogn)` time.

Now, for any `Slope[i,j]`, do a binary search to look for `(b,-a)` and `(-b,a)` in array.

Binary Search for all `n` slopes will take `O(nlogn)` time.

So, total **Time Complexity** :

```
= Calculate slope between all points + Sort the slopes + BinarySearch 
= O(n*(n+nlogn+nlogn)) = O(n^2log(n))
```

**Note** :

1. Make sure to **normalize** the Slope Vector, i.e. :

   `coordinate_a = (p,q)
     coordinate_b = (r,s)
     slope_vector(a,b) = (p-r,q-s)/distance(a,b)`
2. Joint of Right Angled Triangle : Common coordinate between two orthogonal edges.

Comment: when looking for (b,-a) and (-b,a) if both of them are present we would still be adding only one to the answer while we should be adding two, what would we do in that case?